# Calculation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-calculation

```
var pricePerItemExVat = parseInt($("#ConsumerWSP").val()) / parseInt($("#ConsumerItemSellUnit").val());
var pricePerItemIncVat = pricePerItemExVat + (pricePerItemExVat * parseInt($("#pricingConsumerVat").text()));
var consumerPor = ((parseInt($("#itemRRP").val()) - pricePerItemIncVat) / parseInt($("#itemRRP").val())) * 100;
alert(consumerPor);
```

Even when all my fields have values(and also values greater than ZERO) the alert returns me a `NaN`.

Why Is it so ?

How may I do this calculation in javascript ?

Comment: Can you create fiddle?

Comment: Can you show us what each variable equals?

Answer (score 0):

You have get the text in-place of value. As per code you are trying to pricePerItemExVat divide by Empty. So  pricePerItemIncVat value is "NaN".

```
$("#pricingConsumerVat").text()));
```

[image]

Let me know if any concern.

**Edit 1:**

```
var pricePerItemExVat = parseInt($("#ConsumerWSP").val()) / parseInt($("#ConsumerItemSellUnit").val());
alert(pricePerItemExVat );
var pricePerItemIncVat = pricePerItemExVat + (pricePerItemExVat * parseInt($("#pricingConsumerVat").val()));
alert(pricePerItemIncVat );
var consumerPor = ((parseInt($("#itemRRP").val()) - pricePerItemIncVat) / parseInt($("#itemRRP").val())) * 100;
alert(consumerPor);
```

Comment: I had tried with $("#pricingConsumerVat").val())); too , didnt worked.

Comment: Can you please put alert on every variable? For reference please check 'edit1' in above code snippet.  Please provide value of each alert.

Comment: NaN  ... for each alert.

Comment: Can you please provide each textbox's value?

Comment: jayesh thx very much for your concern bhai , I solved the problem. I used Math.round() instead of parseInt(). cheers.